# Get Difference between two Dates from DatePicker

Tags: android

Creating app in which i am using DatePicker.I have created two DatePicker and setting selected date on TextView.Now i want to get duration or difference between two dates selected from DatePicker .I have created method to set difference but i don't know how to set TextView Value when calling method.

```
String startDateFromText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartDate)).getText().toString();
String endDateFromText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTOREndDate)).getText().toString();`
```

calling this method:

```
difference(?,?);



private void difference(Date startDate, Date endDate) {

    long diff = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime()));

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

   long elapsedDays = diff / daysInMilli;
    diff = diff % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = diff / hoursInMilli;
    diff = diff % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = diff / minutesInMilli;
    diff = diff % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = diff / secondsInMilli;

    Log.e("Difference is",elapsedDays +":"+ elapsedHours +":"+ elapsedMinutes +":"+ elapsedSeconds);
}
```

Comment: Why not use some library? Like joda-time

Comment: not sure what the question is but if you want to set the value to your textview you can use textview.setText("Value String");

Answer (score 0):

To set TextView Value when calling method use textView.setText("your string");